# How can I run query and reload page?

Tags: javascript, php

The doubt is the next one...

I have a query that I want to create when entering the page in order to obtain an ID that I want to put in an input to enter records with their respective created id that is unique per day ...

The query if the problem is executed is that once the page is loaded it creates it but to get the id, I must refresh the page again and get the id in my inputs, I would like to see the way to create the query and then my Website cool down.

```html
$QueryLineAdd="INSERT INTO psb_smt.psb_info (linea, DateTime, EndDate)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '".$_GET['line']."', '".$StarDate." ".$TimeNow."', '".$EndDate." 06:39:00') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT DateTime, EndDate, linea FROM psb_smt.psb_info WHERE linea = '".$_GET['line']."' AND 
    DateTime >= '".$StarDate." 06:40:00' AND EndDate<='".$EndDate." 06:39:00'
) LIMIT 1";

$ResultLineAdd=mysqli_query($con,$QueryLineAdd);
```

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should address imminently

Comment: It seems that you might be doing this the wrong way. If your page is creating an id that you need on load, can you get the id and execute the query before the page loads? If for some reason you can't do that, you would need to use ajax in order to call the back end method to get the proper values.

Comment: I need to create that query to then fill out a form where I get an id of that query created at the time of entering the page, how can I create that query when entering the site and continue with my form.

Answer (score 0):

If I do get it right, the query that you are executing returns some id, lets say NNN. Make sure you **have no output on that page** and then just do a header location:

`header("Location: http://www.example.com/?id=NNN");`

If you have output before that you will get headers already sent warning and you will not be able to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

you don't refresh a page because of an ID. you either pass it as an encrypted query string like 
https://example.com/somepage?id=AXYHNJK76PLOUY09YTTV4CDF
let's say id here is 2 then grab it by $id = $_GET['id'].

OR use Javascript to call an API that queries what you need. DO NOT FORGET to put all security measures in place when using this method.

IN YOUR CASE:
run the query before before the HTML out put:

```
<?php
run query here
$queryResultId = your query that returns a result;
$encryptedId = encryptionfunction($queryResultId);
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type ="hidden" name="id_of_something" value="<?php echo 
$encryptedId; ?>" />
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know what the ID is for but remember you never expose an ID of a database to internet. least you can do is encrypt it with Hash and Salt.

Answer (score -1):

Make php file as backend ( don't use it as page), write page in html (maybe with some php templating) then call function with js from site, also don't concat query that's very insecure), use binding from mysqli or better use pdo.

Comment: Can it be something like that?

`$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btnagregar').click(function(){
   var datos=$('#frmpsb').serialize();
   $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"adline.php",
    data:datos,
    success:function(r){
     if(r==1){
      $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
     }else{
      alert('Fallo al enviar la peticion.');
     }
    }
   });
  });
 });`

Comment: PHP:
adline.php

`<?php
$conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','psb_smt');

$linea=$_GET['line'];

$QueryLineAdd="INSERT INTO psb_smt.psb_info (linea, DateTime, EndDate)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '".$linea."', '".$StarDate." ".$TimeNow."', '".$EndDate." 06:39:00') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT DateTime, EndDate, linea FROM psb_smt.psb_info WHERE linea = '".$linea."' AND 
    DateTime >= '".$StarDate." 06:40:00' AND EndDate<='".$EndDate." 06:39:00'
) LIMIT 1";

echo mysqli_query($conexion,$QueryLineAdd);
?>`

Comment: Js is fine, but in php file you use $linea which is undeclared yet, I suppose you pass data with post payload so in query building you have to use $_POST var, also mysqli_query() query returns mysqli_result object which don't have data explicitly, you need to fetch query here is pseudo code:  `$res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);  $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)`

Comment: I advise you to make some play with `var_dump()` function to see what exactly does mysqli_* function, also read  mysqli documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: I already managed to create the query by clicking on the button, but in order to obtain the created id I have to update my site which is the appropriate way to obtain that value without reloading the entire site and already be able to obtain that id in my form when opening my modal ?